# Conditions on Existential Generalization in an axiomatic proof system

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the axiomatic proof system that I am using, I have Existential Generalization (EG).

So an instance of EG is the following.

$(Fx \land Gx) \rightarrow \exists z (Fz \land Gz)$

But is the following a valid instance of EG?

$(Fx \land Gx) \rightarrow \exists z (Fx \land Gz)$

Now, usually Existential Generalization is given where the consequent quantifies and replaces *every* instance of a variable (or term). So would my second instance of EG be an incorrect instance since I only replaced and quantified one of the $x$'s in the consequent?

If my second instance is not a valid use of (EG), is there any quick way to prove the second instance using (EG) and perhaps some other intermediary steps?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your presentation of existential generalization, you're right that the candidate example you give is not a valid instance. It would, however, be fine to expand the rule to allow it since it is derivable.

Basically:

- From $Fx\wedge Gx$ infer $Fx$ and $Gx$ separately via the conjunction elimination rules.
- Apply existential generalization to $Gx$ to get $\exists z(Gz)$, and then existential instantiation to *that* to get $Gc$ for a fresh symbol $c$.
- Using conjunction introduction, get $Fx\wedge Gc$.
- Now apply existential generalization, replacing $c$ this time, to that to get $\exists z(Fx\wedge Gz)$.

---

Alternatively, and in my opinion more transparently, we could argue **semantically** and then apply the completeness theorem: since any structure-and-variable-assignment pair making $Fx\wedge Gx$ true also makes $\exists z(Fx\wedge Gz)$ true, by the completeness theorem the corresponding inference must be deducible from the rules you already have.

Comment: Is there a quick way to get $(Fx \rightarrow Gx) \rightarrow \exists z (Fx \rightarrow Gz)$ using existential instantiation/generalization and other rules similar to what you did with $\land$?

Answer (score 1):

> usually [Existential Generalization (aka: Existential Introduction)](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) is given where the consequent quantifies and replaces *every instance* of a variable (or term).

Correct. How to get the result describey by @Noah's answer above with Natural Deduction?

We consider $\varphi(x,x)$ meaning that the formula has (at least) two distinct free occurrences of variable $x$.

1. $\varphi(x,x)$
2. $\lnot \exists y \varphi (x,y)$ --- assumed [a]
3. $\varphi (x,y)$ --- assumed [b]
4. $\exists y \varphi (x,y)$
5. $\lnot \varphi (x,y)$ --- using the contradiction 2)-4) and discharging assumption [b]
6. $\forall y \lnot \varphi (x,y)$ --- by UG: correct, because $y$ is not *free* in assumptions above
7. $\lnot \varphi(x,x)$ --- by UI

> 8. $\exists y \varphi (x,y)$ --- using the contradiction 1)-7) by Double Negation, discharging assumption [b].

Answer (score 0):

> From any statement $\varphi(x,x)$ where term $z$ *does not occur*, you may infer $\exists z~\varphi(z,x)$. $$\varphi(x,x)\vdash \exists x~\varphi(z,x)$$

That is :   You do *not* have to replace *all* free instances of $x$.   You can generalise on as many of these instances as you need (including *zero*).

---

Now $x$ is often a witness variable (a fresh variable obtained through *existential instantiation*) and you do not want any occurrences of such to remain in the conclusion.   If you ensure that it does not, then there is no issue.